# C++ stream iterators vs container iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

From what I understand, in C++, for container types (e.g. `vector`, `deque`, `map`), I can get the iterator type using syntax like

```
vector<int>::iterator
map<int,int>::const_iterator
```

And get an actual iterator to first element through a method like

```
stuff.begin()
```

However, for streams (e.g. `ifstream`), the interface seems to be a little different; I can get an iterator by writing

```
streambuf_iterator<char>(fin)
stream_iterator<int>(fin)
```

From what I understand, `ifstream` doesn't have any method `begin<int>` or `beginbuf` the way I had initially expected from my experience with `vector`.

Is there a reason why they are different (technical or historical)? Wouldn't it be more orthogonal and easier for new coders if `istream` iterators behaved more like `vector` and its ilk?

Comment: It's mostly historical--iostreams had been in use for years before iterators came into the picture. There's also a practical problem: a vector is instantiated over a type, so that becomes the type for the iterator. For a stream, you need to directly specify the type your plan to read/write, because a stream can hold objects of arbitrary types.

Answer (score 0):

I think the important distinction to note here is the differences in the structures you're trying to use iterators on. Structures you mentioned, `vector`, `deque` and `map`, are flexible but the state of their contained data is relatively static. On the other hand, a `stream` is something extremely fluid and everchanging, if we look at it as a `stream` should be.

Now, because streams "flow" and continue to change, there is no `begin` or `end` to the stream when observing it as a data object. Obviously this point of view is not absolute but I believe this would be the idealogy followed when designing `stream` iterators.

Answer (score 0):

In fact a stream is no vector. You can imagine a river. A river has no "beginning" water and no "ending" water (except it dries out). A vector is more a row of identical objects. That row has begin and end.

A file has of course a begin and an end, but that is not the way the stream wants to abstract you the file.